# Join two tables on multiple columns with case that return not fully matched raws with replacement of not matched value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table A

| raw_number | ars | bill | codt | c4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 900 | 603121 |  | 123 |
| 2 | 900 | 603121 | YPR-003 | 234 |
| 3 | 900 | 603121 | Psp-123 | 345 |
| 4 | 900 | 603121 |  | 456 |
| 5 | 900 | 603121 |  | 567 |

and table B

| raw_number | ars | bill | codt | s4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 900 | 603121 | Psp-123 | asd |
| 2 | 900 | 603121 |  | zxc |
| 3 | 900 | 455000 |  | F |

Im joining table A with table B on "ars", "bill", "codt" columns.

My point  is getting this result:

| ars | bill | codt | c4 | s4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 900 | 603121 |  | 123 | zxc |
| 900 | 603121 |  | 234 | zxc |
| 900 | 603121 | Psp-123 | 345 | asd |
| 900 | 603121 |  | 456 | zxc |
| 900 | 603121 |  | 567 | zxc |

columns "raw_number" added for explanations :  for raw number 3 from table A match must be raw 1 from table B, cos its fully matched, but raw number 2 from A must match with raw 2 from B

```
SELECT a.ars, a.bill, b.codt, a.c4, b.s4
FROM A a
LEFT JOIN B b ON
a.ars = b.ars AND a.bill = b.bill AND a.codt = b.codt
```

is not working for me cos it returns null values from table B for raw number 3 A table
INNER JOIN is not a point too cos remove this raw

original query is more complicated because tables A and B is a results from another joins

UPDATE:
After an NBK answer i try this

```
SELECT a.ars, a.bill, b.codt, a.c4, b.s4 
FROM A a LEFT JOIN B b ON a.ars = b.ars 
AND a.bill = b.bill 
AND a.codt IS DISTINCT FROM b.codt 
UNION  
SELECT a.ars, a.bill, b.codt, a.c4, b.s4 
FROM A a LEFT JOIN B b ON a.ars = b.ars AND a.bill = b.bill 
AND a.codt = b.codt
```

it looks like i want but im not sure because my original query with this have another unions around and looks monstrous.. 1200+ raws
Maybe someone have another idea?

Comment: are the empyt codt empty strings or NULL

Comment: it contains empty strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will return the data you requested but *s4* is missing.

```
SELECT a.ars, a.bill, b.codt, a.c4, b.s4
  FROM A a
  LEFT JOIN B b ON a.ars = b.ars AND a.bill = b.bill AND a.codt = b.codt and a.codt <> ''
  order by ars, bill, c4
```

This will return :

| ars | bill | codt | c4 | s4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 900 | 603121 | null | 123 | null |
| 900 | 603121 | null | 234 | null |
| 900 | 603121 | Psp-123 | 345 | asd |
| 900 | 603121 | null | 456 | null |
| 900 | 603121 | null | 567 | null |

Then will get *s4* from *table B* when s4 is null using `inner join` :

```
select DISTINCT s.ars, s.bill, s.codt, s.c4, case when s.s4 is not null then s.s4 else b.s4 end as s4 
from B b
inner join (
  SELECT a.ars, a.bill, b.codt, a.c4, b.s4
  FROM A a
  LEFT JOIN B b ON a.ars = b.ars AND a.bill = b.bill AND a.codt = b.codt and a.codt <> ''
) as s on s.ars = b.ars and s.bill = b.bill
where b.codt = ''
order by ars, bill, c4
```

Result :

| ars | bill | codt | c4 | s4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 900 | 603121 | null | 123 | zxc |
| 900 | 603121 | null | 234 | zxc |
| 900 | 603121 | Psp-123 | 345 | asd |
| 900 | 603121 | null | 456 | zxc |
| 900 | 603121 | null | 567 | zxc |

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/fz7Ox1cN)

Answer (score 1):

if codt codt is an emtypoyt string = works, you neeed only take care of the NULL if no match is found

```
CREATE TABLE A (
  "raw_number" INTEGER,
  "ars" INTEGER,
  "bill" INTEGER,
  "codt" VARCHAR(7),
  "c4" INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO A
  ("raw_number", "ars", "bill", "codt", "c4")
VALUES
  ('1', '900', '603121','', '123'),
  ('2', '900', '603121', 'YPR-003', '234'),
  ('3', '900', '603121', 'Psp-123', '345'),
  ('4', '900', '603121', '', '456'),
  ('5', '900', '603121', '', '567');
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

> ```
> INSERT 0 5
> ```

```
CREATE TABLE B (
  "raw_number" INTEGER,
  "ars" INTEGER,
  "bill" INTEGER,
  "codt" VARCHAR(7),
  "s4" VARCHAR(3)
);

INSERT INTO B
  ("raw_number", "ars", "bill", "codt", "s4")
VALUES
  ('1', '900', '603121', 'Psp-123', 'asd'),
  ('2', '900', '603121', '', 'zxc'),
  ('3', '900', '455000', '', 'F');
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

> ```
> INSERT 0 3
> ```

```
SELECT a.ars, a.bill, a.codt, a.c4, COALESCE(b.s4,(SELECT s4 FROM B b1 WHERE a.ars = b1.ars AND a.bill = b1.bill and codt = ''))
FROM A a
LEFT JOIN B b ON
a.ars = b.ars AND a.bill = b.bill AND a.codt = b.codt
```

| ars | bill | codt | c4 | coalesce |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 900 | 603121 |  | 123 | zxc |
| 900 | 603121 |  | 456 | zxc |
| 900 | 603121 |  | 567 | zxc |
| 900 | 603121 | Psp-123 | 345 | asd |
| 900 | 603121 | YPR-003 | 234 | zxc |

> ```
> SELECT 5
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/P4nSx_yC)
t

Comment: this returns me only raw num 2 from expected result, maybe i should union this with standard left join result

Comment: `SELECT a.ars, a.bill, b.codt, a.c4, b.s4
FROM A a
LEFT JOIN B b ON
a.ars = b.ars AND a.bill = b.bill AND a.codt IS DISTINCT FROM b.codt
UNION 
SELECT a.ars, a.bill, b.codt, a.c4, b.s4
FROM A a
LEFT JOIN B b ON
a.ars = b.ars AND a.bill = b.bill AND a.codt = b.codt`

looks like what i need but not sure

Comment: i added a fiddle to show you how it would wor for your sample data

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, you want to match the `codt` value that exists in A but not in B with the empty string `codt` from B, you could check the existence of `codt` in B before joining as the following:

```
SELECT a.ars, a.bill, b.codt, a.c4, b.s4
FROM 
  (
    select ars, bill, 
      case 
        when 
         exists(select 1 from B d where d.ars=t.ars and d.bill=t.bill and d.codt= t.codt) then codt 
        else '' 
      end as codt, c4
   from A t
  ) a
LEFT JOIN B b ON
a.ars = b.ars AND a.bill = b.bill AND a.codt = b.codt
ORDER BY c4
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/bsJPjMZA)